# Arguments are not passing into command prompt

Tags: c#, command-prompt

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/c opencvproject.exe " + @appPath + @"\\bin\\Debug\\center\\centerilluminate.jpg");

p.Start();
```

I tried this at my other computer and it works , however when I tried it in my new computer this doesn't work somehow. Anyone knows how to solve this? The program I am using is `c#` and im calling cmd to call `c++` program which is opencvproject.exe

There are still multiple instances where I use cmd to trigger other `c++` program and python scripts to run and those are not working too. I am not sure what am I doing wrong..

Comment: Did you check the location of `opencvproject.exe` is in your `PATH` variable on that new computer?

Comment: What do u mean? can you explain it?

Comment: Sure. See [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/q/284342/94017) on [su].

Comment: Does appPath contain spaces? If yes, you must protect it with `"` so that the path won't be split into multiple parameters.

Comment: Hi, I think I somehow get what it does , so how do I implement it in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold the path between double quotation.

```
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c opencvproject.exe \"" + appPath + "\\bin\\Debug\\center\\centerilluminate.jpg\"");
```

**Explanation**

Character combinations consisting of a backslash () followed by a letter or by a combination of digits are called "escape sequences."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/h21280bw.aspx

@ makes escape sequence no effect, so..

```
var s1 = @"\\bin\\Debug\\";  // This contains wrong path \\bin\\Debug\\
var s2 = "\\bin\\Debug\\";   // This contains right path \bin\Debug\
```

And need using escape sequence to hold the double quotation between double quotation.

```
var s3 = "\"\\bin\\Debug\\\"";  // This contains "\bin\Debug\"
var s4 = @"\"\\bin\\Debug\\\"";  // compile error
```

Comment: Hi, this works like a charm ! mind explaining how this works?

Answer (score 0):

The @ character automatically escapes characters in the string behind it, so you shouldn't double backslash your path.

Eg, where you have:
`@"\\bin\\debug\\.."`

it should either be:
`@"\bin\debug\..."`

or:
`"\\bin\\debug\\.."` (without the @)

Also, if your `apppath` contains spaces, then you should surround the entire string with " characters